# Is there any way to hide the taskbar on the full screen start menu?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, fullscreen

Is there any way in Windows 10 to hide the taskbar on the full screen start menu mode?

I want to hide it so It can looks like Windows 8

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in option in Windows to completely hide the Taskbar (other than setting it to Auto-hide). Using [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) or a similar 3rd party tool, you can hide the Taskbar using it's Windows Class name.

Command-line to hide the Taskbar

```
nircmd.exe win hide class Shell_TrayWnd
```

And to show the taskbar, use:

```
nircmd.exe win show class Shell_TrayWnd
```

References:

[How to Hide the Taskbar Completely in Windows](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/hide-taskbar-completely-windows/)

[NirCmd's `win` command-line parameter reference](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

Comment: But I want to hide it only when I'm on the full screen start menu

Comment: Easier option would be to create 2 shortcuts (one to hide, another one to show), and assign a hotkey. For example, `Ctrl + Alt + S` can be assigned to show taskbar, and `Ctrl + Alt + H` can be assigned to hide it.

There is no automatic way to do that.